# Django receives incomplete POST data

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am posting json-formatted data to the backend written with Django 3.1.2. However, the data does not seem to received correctly.

js code:

```js
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://" + window.location.host + "/upload/", true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.send(encodeURI("data=" + json));
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
    console.log("Done!");
}
```

Django:

```py
data = request.POST.get('data')
f = open('data.txt', 'w+')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

The data written in the file is incomplete. Nor is it complete when I try to print it. What might be the problem? Is it because the json string I post is too long?

Comment: Do you really have a missing trailing paren here: httpRequest.send(encodeURI("data=" + json); or is that a paste error?

Comment: A paste error. I did not actually get an error with my code. The only problem is my failure to get the complete data at the backend.

Comment: What do you mean by incomplete? That's somehow like `{"key": "va`?

Comment: The json string posted is an extremely long one, but the data I get at the backend consists only of the first 50 or so characters of the original data. The rest of the json is gone.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by making this little change with my python code:

```py
# data = request.POST.get('data')
data = request.body.decode('utf-8')
```

Nevertheless, I still do not understand why this works in my case.